# GPU'S and Hybrid Processing Units

Tags: gpu

How do GPU's and Hybrid Processing Units differ in terms of computing resources and their interconnection? How does this effect parallel processing beneficially or negatively?

Comment: Googling "hybrid processing unit" gives no relevant hits. Are you sure this is a thing? If so, are you sure you have the name right?

Comment: "hybrid processing unit" as in a hybrid multiprocessor

Comment: Intel's Ivy Bridge processor is an example of an HPU

Comment: You need to expand what you mean by hybrid microprocessor: this is not a commonly used term, possibly because of the vast ambiguity of the word "hybrid". In particular, I have no idea why Ivy Bridge is a hybrid.

Comment: I am as dumbfounded as you guys. This is a homework question in my computer organization class and I do not understand it. Here is the whole question "How do GPUs and HPUs (like Intel Ivy Bridge) differ 
in terms of computing resources and their interconnection? How does this benefit and/or penalize parallel processing (express your answer in terms of Amdahl’s Law)?"

Comment: I think an HPU is a mix of SIMD, MIMD,....etc